# Switch between Widget within a column

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a Column like this and I would like to switch between `PageOne(), PageTwo(), PageThree() here with transition` on the comment i've written on the code, how exactly do I do that?

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
        Row( 
            children:[
                        Text("Test")
            ]
        ),
        // I would like to switch between PageOne(), PageTwo(), PageThree() here with transition left to right or vice versa
  ]
)
```

I tried the code below in `onTap of a button` and it does not work. I've received error saying **No material widget found. List tile widgets require a  Material ancestor widget.**

```js
Widget resSlide = PageOne(); //default page
//Inside onTap of a button
Navigator.push(
                context,
                PageTransition(
                    type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight,
                    child: dataIndex == 1 ? resSlide = PageOne() : dataIndex == 2 ? resSlide = PageTwo() : resSlide = PageThree())
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IndexedStack to switch between these pages . Every page should have specific index . Please check this url : https://o7planning.org/13227/flutter-indexedstack

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Is it possible to make animation like `LeftToRight` or `RightToLeft` while I switch between these 3 pages? Also is it doable that when I switch from `PageOne to PageThree` there's a fast forward `LeftToRight` animated transition?

Comment: Yes , there is AnimatedSwitcher in flutter which you can use it eith IndexedStack . Check this url : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48217

Comment: Is this going to work https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition ? But how do I use it within the `Column` as I'm not making a full page transition, just the bottom part of the screen